# Iterated chaos expansion

Tags: pr.probability, polynomials, gaussian, orthogonal-polynomials, chaos

Using the notations from [Normal Approximations with Malliavin Calculus, Chapter 2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/normal-approximations-with-malliavin-calculus/E5FEB0C436B3F164C10565AC39214454)
random variables $F$ in the probability space generated by an iso-normal Gaussian family $X(h)$,
$$E[X(h)X(g)] = \langle h,g\rangle_H, \quad E[X(h)]=0$$
indexed by elements of some Hilbert space $h\in H$ admit the chaos expansion
$$F = E[F] + \sum_{p\ge 1} I_p\Bigl(\frac{E[D^p F]}{p!}\Bigr).$$
Here $D^p F\in H^{\otimes p}$ denotes the $p$-th Malliavin derivative, and $I_p$ denotes the $p$-th multiple integral.

I am wondering, whether such expansions can be iterated in a straightforward way. For instance, for
$$F=\sum_{p\ge 1} I_p (f_p), \quad f_p\in H^p$$
and smooth scalar functions $\phi\colon \mathbf R\to\mathbf R$, how can the chaos expansion of $\phi(F)$ be obtained from the chaos expansion of $F$?

I tried to write
$$\phi(F)=E[\phi(F)] + \sum_{q\ge 1} I_q\Bigl(\frac{E[D^q \phi(F)]}{q!}\Bigr)$$
but evaluating $E[D^q \phi(F)]$ does not seem straightforward. For $q=1$ the chain rule gives
$$E[D\phi(F)]=E[\phi'(F)DF]=\sum_{p\ge 1} p! E[\phi'(F) I_{p-1}(f_p)] $$
it does not seem obvious how to continue.

Comment: Malliavin Derivatives have a form of chain rule as well eg. see Nualart's book. But yes you will still get $\phi'(F)$ since $F$ is possibly random and thus correlated with its iterated derivatives. Unless $\phi$ is some polynomial (and so by iterated integration by parts reduce it to constants), I don't see how you can get around having $\phi'(F)$ in the expression.

Comment: I know the chain rule. Could you expand how to work out the expansion in the polynomial case using integration by parts? From the cited book I am familiar with the integration by parts formula $E[F I_p(f)] = E\langle D^p F, f\rangle$ by I don't see how this helps to compute the iterated chaos expansion

Comment: right, so by taking enough derivatives, you kill any powers of the polynomial, so I am guessing it will be some shifted expansion.